# Passing argument to class instantiated by framework? (Python Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I have the following setting:

```
import sys 

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful

from model import Model

try:
    gModel = Model(int(sys.argv[1]))
except IndexError, pExc:
    gModel = Model(100)


def main():
    lApp = Flask(__name__)
    lApi = restful.Api(lApp)
    lApi.add_resource(FetchJob, '/')
    lApp.run(debug=True)


class FetchJob(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        lRange = gModel.getRange()
        return lRange


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a way to instantiate the Model-class inside the main()-function? Here, the Flask framework instantiates the FetchJob-class, so that I cannot provide it the parameters it forwards during the instantiation process.

I don't like to have global variables as this messes up the whole design ...

Comment: Hungarian notation? Please, just no....

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work, although I'm not familiar with Flask:

```
import functools

def main():
    try:
        gModel = Model(int(sys.argv[1]))
    except IndexError as pExc:
        gModel = Model(100)
    lApp = Flask(__name__)
    lApi = restful.Api(lApp)
    lApi.add_resource(functools.partial(FetchJob, gModel), '/')
    lApp.run(debug=True)


class FetchJob(restful.Resource):

    def __init__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        restfult.Resource.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.obj = obj

    def get(self):
        lRange = self.obj.getRange()
        return lRange
```

Comment: I would use a classmethod on `FetchJob` for this instead. `FetchJob.as_view()` which returns a callable.

Comment: Sorry, the functools-version does not work for me. I am getting an AttributeError: 

    `'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'`

This corresponds to the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects. According to that, partial-objects behave differently compared to "normal" objects.

Comment: If you are looking at the edit history of my post, there was a `lambda version` as well — everything is the same, but this line is changning: `lApi.add_resource(lambda *args, **kwargs: FetchJob(gModel, *args, **kwargs)`. Try this one out, and let me know if that worked for you.